Are these three structures pavilions in American and Canadian English?
Are these three structures pavilions in American and Canadian English?




Aren't pergolas those slated roof structures?

Have you done any research?

Yes, but first of all, why is research necessary in this case? And secondly, no offense, but the question is for AmE speakers.

Pergolas tend to have open lattice "roofs" (maybe with some vines intertwined in the lattice) and pavilions have roofs that will keep you dry in the rain.  At least that's the case here in southeastern Pennsylvania, about an hour away from Lancaster County, where your middle picture, with the steep gable roof and stone chimney, is from.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pavilion#examples

See https://www.projectsmallhouse.com/blog/2021/01/yardistry-outdoor-rooms-gazebos-and-pavilions/  These are called gazebos and pavilions in AmE.

Thank you but are the first two pavilions and the third one is a gazebo?

(Canadian English) They could be called gazebos or pavilions. The third one is somewhat more likely to be a tent because of the fabric, or even a vague-sounding "structure".
A gazebo should have all rigid elements. A pavilion could be rigid or non-rigid.
I'm much more likely to use "pavilion" functionally rather than formally. That is, a pavilion is a gazebo or tent or structure set up for a particular purpose, whether temporary (at a fair) or permanent (in a park).
